# In graph theory, what is the difference between a "trail" and a "path"?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I'm reading [Combinatorics and Graph Theory, 2nd Ed.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387797106), and am beginning to think the terms used in the book might be outdated. Check out the following passage:

> If the vertices in a walk are distinct, then the walk is called a path. If the edges in a walk are distinct, then the walk is called a trail. In this way, every path is a trail, but not every trail is a path. Got it?

On the other hand, [Wikipedia's glossary of graph theory terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Walks) defines trails and paths in the following manner:

> A trail is a walk in which all the edges are distinct. A closed trail has been called a tour or circuit, but these are not universal, and the latter is often reserved for a regular subgraph of degree two.
>
> Traditionally, a path referred to what is now usually known as an open walk. Nowadays, when stated without any qualification, a path is usually understood to be simple, meaning that no vertices (and thus no edges) are repeated.

Am I to understand that [Combinatorics and Graph Theory, 2nd Ed.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387797106) is using a now outdated definition of path, referring to what is now referred to as an open walk? What are the canonical definitions for the terms "walk", "path", and "trail"?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood something: the definitions in the book are the same as those given as current by Wikipedia.

Comment: You may be right. Specifically, I only just realized that paths have distinct *vertices*, whereas trails have distinct *edges*.

Comment: Indeed you are right, I misread the text. If you post your comment as an answer I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: Done — and perhaps a little more clearly.

Comment: Here is the lecture note from my graph theory class, the author and Prof is Dr.Charles Suffel, I added some examples aside to help classify path and trail.
[path&trail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKKR0.jpg) Feel free to correct me if I am wrong, I am actually a CS girl.....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood something, probably the definitions in the book: they’re actually the same as the definitions that Wikipedia describes as the current ones.

Answer (score 1):

A walk of length k is a non-empty alternating sequence of vertices and edges in G.

A walk is a trail if any edge is traversed at most once.

A trail is a path if any vertex is visited at most once except possibly the initial and terminal vertices when they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Today I also faced the same problem for reading these very first concepts. My understanding is as follows.

Path: A path is a simple graph whose vertices can be ordered so that two vertices are adjoint iff they are constitutive in the list.

Walk: it is a list of vertices and edges $v_0, e_1, v_1, \dots, e_k, v_k$ for $1\le i \le k$, $e_i$ has an endpoints $v_{i-1}, v_i$.

Trial: It is an walk with no repeated edge.

Answer (score 0):

In a trail all edges have direction and the end of one edge leads into the start of a new edge.In a path the same applies,but the same vertex can't be visited more than once which can occur in a trail.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Walk:** any sequence starting and ending with *vertices* and having at least one *edge* between any two *vertices* and all *edges* being *incident* to *vertices* before and next to them
**e.g. 1:** [a, e1, b, e1, a, e2, c, e3, d]

**Trail:** a *walk* with none *edges* repeated
**e.g. 2** [a, e1, b, e5, e, e6, d]
**e.g. 3** [a, e2, c, e3, d, e9, g, e10, e, e6, d, e4, b]

**Path:** a *walk* with none *vertices* repeated with the exception of first and last *vertex* of this *walk*
**e.g. 4** [a, e1, b, e4, d]

**e.g. 1** is *walk* but neither *trail* (due to edge **e1** repeated) nor *path* (due to *vertex* **a** repeated)
**e.g. 2** is a *trail* and also a *path* (none *edge* or *vertex* repeated)
**e.g. 3** is a *trail* but not a *path* (due to *vertex* **d** repeated)
**e.g. 4** is a *trail* and also a *path* (none *edge* or *vertex* repeated)

(it's not possible to have a *path* which is not a *trail* as that requires the condition of a *walk* having not repeated *vertices* but repeated *edges* which is impossible because if an *edge* is repeated then at least one of it's *incident vertices* must be repeated)