# trail vs path in Graph Theory v/s Graphical Models

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definition

In my course on [probabilistic graphical models](https://www.coursera.org/course/pgm), I learnt *(quoting from page 36 of the book Probabilistic Graphical Models: Principles and Techniques by the same author)*

- **Path**: We say that X1 , . . . , Xk form a path in the graph K = (X , E) if, for every i = 1, . . . , k − 1,
  we have that either Xi → Xi+1 or Xi —Xi+1 . A path is directed if, for at least one i, we have
  Xi → Xi+1 .
- **Trail**: We say that X1 , . . . , Xk form a trail in the graph K = (X , E) if, for every i = 1, . . . , k − 1, we
  have that Xi <-> Xi+1 . *(<-> means either -> or <- or -)*

However in context of Graph Theory, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517297/in-graph-theory-what-is-the-differ2nce-between-a-trail-and-a-path) and other links on the internet seem to suggest

- **Path**: Walk with no repeated vertex
- **Trail**: Walk with no repeated edges

Are the two terms defined in different ways in contexts of Graphical Models and Graph Theory or am I understanding something wrong?